# Not getting any audio output during Text to speech with Pyttsx3 module on Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, text-recognition, pyttsx

**My python version is 3.7  and Pyaudio version is 2.7** 
Program is totally running during engine init, but I can't use **sipas5** for windows so I have used **dummy**

```
import pyttsx3
    engine = pyttsx3.init("dummy")
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)

    def speak(text):
        print('Rex:' + text)
        engine.say(text)
        engine.runAndWait()

    print("On")
    speak("This program is running perfectly")
    print("End")
```

> Output

```
On
Rex:This program is running perfectly
End

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Dummy isnt a voice engine. Its tk simply test. There are 3 types for pyttsx3. Sapi5, nsss, and espeak. This is what you put inside of that init (). This is the link for the official python package with information.

https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/

Answer (score -1):

Literally just do it right pip3 install pyttxs3 = 2.71

Comment: Please do the markdown formatting right ( https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ) and explain why this command helps. Also consider whether "Literally just do it right" might be perveived as a less friendly way of helping. (I intentionally chose the start of my comment to help you with that. Here is the missing helpful part: you will find a formatting to make code/commands easily recognisable as such. `this way` )